# Match and replace by regex, but do replace only for some part found by regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have to match string for specific regexp and do replace (replace with nothing). However, during replace I have to replace only part of regexp matched. See below.

I have the following regexp:

```
var regex1 = RegExp('[\s.,:\*]+' + word + '?s?i?\s*:?\s*', 'gi');
```

This regexp should match (at least, I hope so) all occurences of:

- word (for example "testword") `word`
- there should be at least one `whitespace, dot, comma, : or *` symbol exactly before this word `[\s.,:\*]+` and no other symbols in between this and `word`
- there could be some other specific symbols (including `s` and `i` letters) exactly after the word `'?s?i?\s*:?\s*'` and nothing else

For instance, matches would be `.testword` ; `,testwords`; `:.testword`.

I am replacing these occurences with "nothing":  `str = str.replace(regex1, "")`.

However, I do not need to replace first part: `[\s.,:\*]+`. I want it to stay. So in string

```
          "Some words .testword"
should be "Some words ."
I have    "Some words"    (there is no dot at the end).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you must define `\` in a string literal with double `\`. `'[\s.,:\*]+'` => `'[\\s.,:*]+'`. Wrap it with a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and use a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) in the replacement. `RegExp('([\\s.,:*]+)' + word + 's?i?\\s*:?\\s*', 'gi');` and replace with `"$1"`, not `""`.

```js
var s  = "Some words .testword";
var word="testword";
var rx = RegExp('([\\s.,:*]+)' +word + 's?i?\\s*:?\\s*', 'gi');
console.log(s.replace(rx, "$1"));
```

The `$1` will insert the part of string "sub"matched with the `([\\s.,:*]+)`
 regex part.